# Form Submission and URI rewriting

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

I have a fairly standard CI3 site up and running. I have created my own base controller, called `MY_Controller`, and all my page controllers extend this.

`MY_Controller.php`

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Display the view. This function wraps up all the teplates,
 * sets the page title, adds all the requested Javascript and CSS, 
 * and passes along any data.
 * @param string $view The name of the content view to display
 * @param array $data (Optional) ÏAn array of any data to pass along
 */
protected function showView($view, $data = null) {

    if ($data === null) {
        $data = array();
    }

    // call all the template pieces
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('mainNav', $data);
    $this->load->view($view, $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

Each page controller calls `$this->showView($viewName, $data);` when it's ready to display results or whatever.

I have a form located on my login controller, `Login.php`.

Login.php has a method called "submit".

```
public function submit() {

    $cfg = array(
        array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|min_length[3]|max_length[50]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|min_length[3]|max_length[50]'
        )
    );

    if ($this->form_validation->set_rules($cfg) === false) {
        $this->showView("login");
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );

        if (filter_var($this->input->post('username'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
        } else {
            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('username');
        }

        $user = $this->User->getUserFromLogin($data);

        if ($user !== false) {

            $sessionData = array(
                'userName'  => $user->userName,
                'email'     => $user->email,
                'authToken' => $user->authToken,
                'lastSeen'  => date("Y-m-d")
            );
            // Add user data to session
            $this->session->set_userdata('userLoggedIn', true);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userData', $sessionData);
            $this->showView("home");

        } else {
            $data = array(
                'error_message' => 'User could not be loaded.',
            );
            $this->showView("login", $data);
        }
    }
}
```

My Login view, `login.php`

```html
<div class="wrapper style1">
  <article id="work">
    <header>
      <h2>Login!</h2>
      <?=validation_errors();?>
    </header>
    <div class="container 50%">
      <section>
        <form method="post" action="login/submit">
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="6u">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username or email" value="<?=set_value('username');?>" />
              </div>
              <div class="6u">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="12u">
                <ul class="actions">
                  <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign in!" />
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <footer>
          <div>...or sign in with Facebook!</div>
          <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
        </footer>
      </section>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Upon successful submission of the form, I'm expecting it to redirect me to `home`, which it is, however, the URI is `localhost/login/submit` instead of `localhost/home`.

Likewise with my logout controller, upon logout, it navigates to the URI `localhost/logout/logout`, which generates a 404.

I can't figure out why it doesn't redirect to the controller I've specified in the `showView()` method.

I'm not using any custom routing tricks.

Answer (score 1):

The method showView simply loads in the values extra templates you want as well as the data you sent. I believe you are looking to do a redirect when you need to move off of pages instead of just rerendering the page the way you are.

```
redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
```

If this doesn't suffice your needs please include you routes and your logout controller to see what's going on in the other scenario you mentioned.

Comment: Using `redirect` instead of calling my `showView` seems to do what I want, however, I still feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: If it doesn't work post the blocks I mentioned to give me the new data to assist you.

Comment: BTW, my routes file is simply the default. I feel like perhaps I'm missing routing rules, and the understanding of WHY I must have said routing rules to simple submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

On successful authentication, instead of

```
$this->showView("home");
```

you should change that to `redirect()`,

```
redirect("controller/method/parameters if any");
```

Answer (score 0):

there is method call `showview()`. To load view you have to use

```
$this->load->view("login");
```

as well as redirect should be

```
redirect('controller_name/method_name');
```